# what's this symbol mean ( square with 3 curved lines)

Tags: notification-icons, screencast

[image]

The leftmost icon(rectangular) on above screen shot showed up yesterday. I don't know, where or what app it's for but I would like it gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This symbol is of "Cast screen" found in Android which is used to cast your screen to a television. This symbol in the status bar means that your phone screen is being casted to a television or cast screen is active:

[image: This symbol]

If you want to get rid of it, just go to settings and disable screen casting.

More info:
[Google Support](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6059461?hl=en-IN)

Comment: Okay thanks man. I didn't turn screen casting. But again thanks have a good day

Comment: Some screen recording apps may also use it to record your screen, so if you are using any screen recording software(as it appears in your screenshot) this might be due to it.

Comment: Here is a relevant article on the topic: https://www.technipages.com/google-pixel-connect-to-tv